# how to align an image at the bottom of a viewport div inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, viewport, twitter-bootstrap-2

i'm working on bootstrap 2.3.2 and i want to position an image at the bottom of a viewport div, but unable to do so.i want  that the secondlayer image will remain at the bottom of viewport div in every device. How can i achieve this.

Here is my code for carousel:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="bgImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600" alt="First slide">             
            </div>
            <div class="header-text">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6 offset3">
                            <div class="firstlayer">
                                <img src="http://projects.flashonmind.in/jaldiad/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/slider01-text.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <div class="secondlayer">
                                <img src="http://projects.flashonmind.in/jaldiad/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/slider01-bottomImage01.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}
.carousel-inner .item .bgImage img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
    padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
    padding: 15px;
}


/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.text-center {text-align:center;}
.firstlayer {margin-top:180px;}
.secondlayer {margin-top:175px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the `secondlayer` div positioned at the bottom of the viewport, it has to be positioned `absolutely`. See the revised code of your example:

```css
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #2980b9;
}
.carousel-inner .item .bgImage img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
    padding: 15px;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
    padding: 15px;
}


/* Carousel Header Styles */
.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.text-center {text-align:center;}
.firstlayer {margin-top:180px;}
.secondlayer {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center;
}
.secondlayer img {
    max-width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="bgImage">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600" alt="First slide">             
            </div>
            <div class="header-text">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6 offset3">
                            <div class="firstlayer">
                                <img src="http://projects.flashonmind.in/jaldiad/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/slider01-text.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="secondlayer">
                <img src="http://projects.flashonmind.in/jaldiad/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/slider01-bottomImage01.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```